# Is it possible to override the default Connector class implementation in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, endpoint

From the tomcat 6 documentation it looks like you can set the classname of things like the Context (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html), Engine (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/engine.html), and Host (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html), but not the Connector.

Am I missing something here or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "protocol" attribute on the Connector element is really a class name. It's just that tomcat knows a few special values such as "HTTP/1.1" here to be a bit more friendly.

You could do

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="com.example.MyConnector" >
```

Comment: Ha! Plain as day in the documentation but I guess I just breezed over protocol meaning anything other than the actual protocol. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to implement your own connector (We have 2 custom impl. on your servers), you need to implement the protocol and all the jazz form there

for instance:

```
public class Http11NioInterceptor extends Http11NioProtocol {`
  public Http11NioInterceptor(){    
    super();
    ep = new NioEndpointX();
//....
  }
////
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: If I were contributing this to a standard tomcat install, how would I go about doing it? I can of course do this for an embedded install, but would I need to edit the server.xml in some way I'm not familiar?

Comment: @Zack, you have to put it in server.xml and set protocol to your impl. <Connector
         port="8080"
         address="xxx.yyy"
         maxThreads="100"
         maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
         protocol="packname.xxx.Http11NioInterceptor"

Comment: This isn't really using a custom Connector but rather modifying the behavoir of the Connector by overwriting the Protocol that is used by the Connector. In tomcat 8.0 (maybe previous versions as well) createRequest() creates a catalina.Connector.Request. This behavior can't be modified by a custom Protocol.